# Calculating full shade coverage

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Apologies in advance, I'm neither a student nor a mathematician (I'm not even sure how to tag this :P )

Basically, I'm using some home automation software (Home Assistant) to alert me when to close/open the blinds and windows on hot summer days.  This is very easy for my East/West windows (in the example below, `Window a` and `Window c`), as the software provides updating Azimuth values for my location.

My problem, however, is that I have a fairly critical window (the bedroom window) that is nestled inside a corner (see the example image).  Based on the example image, What equation would tell me when `Window b` will be in full shade?

[image]

I have measured:

- The length of the wall casting the shadow (Length A)
- The length of the wall with the window (Length B)
- The distance from the roof to the top of the window (Length C)
- The distance from the edge of the window to the edge of the wall (Length D)

The Home Assistant software I'm using provides minute-by-minute updates on the Sun's

- elevation (let's call it X)
- azimuth (Let's call it Y)

This is where my highschool math skills from 20 years ago fall apart.  How to I determine what values of the sun's Elevation (X) and Azimuth (Y) will put my window in full shade given the lengths A, B, C, and D?

Help!

Please and Thank you.

Comment: What is the orientation of the house?

Comment: @ jkms: Why is the shadow near window  b from line A suddenly taking a turn?

Comment: You mean window "b" - right?

Comment: @rogerl "window b" is facing south